# Installing vue to laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm

i tried to install a vuejs to laravel like explained in this web page
https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/how-to-install-vue-js-in-laravel-8-tutorial/
and in a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SY_JlmU8Dyg .
Currentli version i have: npm -v: 7.11.1, node -v v15.11.0 and in routes/web.php putting Route::get('ver', fn () => dd(app()->version()));, writing "php artisan serve" and http://127.0.0.1:8000/ver displays 8.53.0.
Many times i dried to put carefully to work the vue. Reached to command
npm run dev
some where i found that "npn install && npm run dev". && doesn't work in my Windows10-computer, then "npm install" and "npm run dev".
Frist time running "npm run dev" I receive

```
> dev
> npm run development

> development  /*these tree lines are green*/

    Additional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.
 
    Running: npm install vue-template-compiler vue-loader@^15.9.7 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps
 
    Finished. Please run Mix again.
```

And the next time to running the "npm run dev" i received:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue> npm install

up to date, audited 792 packages in 2s

82 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

And again running this command

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue> npm run dev

> dev
> npm run development


> development
> mix
```

And also the red lines ("[webpack-cli]" is white)

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'
Require stack:
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\index.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\Vue.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\components\ComponentRegistrar.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Mix.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\bootstrap.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\plugin-webpack5.js:6:42)   
    at Module._compile (C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\laravel_vue\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30) 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\plugin-webpack5.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\plugin.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\vue-loader\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\components\\Vue.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\components\\ComponentRegistrar.js',     
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\src\\Mix.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\laravel-mix\\setup\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\webpack-cli.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\lib\\bootstrap.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
    'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\laravel_vue\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

Does somebody know how to do?

Comment: Is your webpack installation missing, incomplete or corrupt? Try `npm i webpack --save-dev` in your project root.

Comment: Good recommendation. But works "npm update vue-loader".